# How to solve the Application Error 0xc000007b?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I started to install Oracle in Windows. Downloaded sqlplus and related files (glogin, OCI.dll etc), but sqlplus.exe doesn’t open neither through cmd nor through the folder. When I’m trying to open it computer still always tells me 0xc000007b. What could you recommend me to do please?

Comment: What version of Oracle?  Are you using the full installation software package from Oracle?  What version of Windows?  Home edition or professional edition?

Comment: What exactly did you download?  One generally does not just download `SQL*Plus`, that's installed as part of the Oracle client which is a rather hefty download from OTN.  Maybe you're trying to do an install of the Instant Client (which requires a bit of manual configuration and is generally more appropriate if you're trying to package something with the installer for your application that installs a minimal Oracle client).

Comment: Hi Mark Stewart, Oracle version 19.2, yes, I’m using full installatio package from Oracle. Windows XP. Home edition (usual one). The problem is that after download of a suitable zip-package from Oracle website, the installation through cmd doesn’t go well.

Comment: Hi Justin Cave. As I wrote in my previous comment, I downloaded Oracle 19.2 package and started to install it. For some reason SQL*Plus doesn’t work. What exactly do you mean by „a bit of manual configuration“, could you please recommend to read something about that? And what do you offer to package with the installer? Sorry for these questions if they seem to be simple, I am quite new for programming.